# Conic sections in high dimensions

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, analytic-geometry

Can every $n$-dimensional ellipsoid be obtained as a (spherical) conic section?

This is false for generic quadrics but seems true for ellipsoid.

Does anybody have any references?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is no. A spherical cone is
$$x_0^2=x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2.$$
Intersecting it with a hyperplane $x_0=c^Tx$, where $c$ is a (column) vector we obtain
a quadratic form with martix
$$I-cc^T,$$
that is a rank $1$ perturbation of the unit matrix. The eigenvalues
are found from 
$$0=\det(\lambda I-I+cc^t)=\det((\lambda-1)I+cc^T),$$
so $1-\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $cc^T$. But rank of $cc^T$ is $1$, so $cc^T$
can have at most one non-zero eigenvalue.